# How to change font size without affecting TOC?

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

I'm writing a report in LaTeX and I just made a table of contents. But in my text, I would 
like to increase the font size of my chapters, and sections. Actually, I use this :

`\chapter{\large blah blah blah}`
`\section{\normalsize blih blih blih}`

But I would like to write "blah blah blah" in \Large, and "blih blih blih" in \large. But if
I do that, it also changes the font size in the TOC...

Comment: See [Change size of section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59726/5764) for a canonical answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`sectsty` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty). See more details here: [Change size of section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59726/5764).

If *sectsty* doesn't work for you, and you can't find another package that would work, then you can modify the `.cls` file to change the default font size of these elements.

Another alternative is a quick hack is setting `\def\large{} \def\normalsize{}` just above `\tableofcontents`:

```
{\def\large{} \def\normalsize{} \tableofcontents}
```

Comment: The proper way is *not* to modify this in the class file, but rather using packages in the document preamble. Specifically, the [`sectsty` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) can do this easily. Here's a more canonical take on this: [Change size of section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59726/5764)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Added it to my answer.